# Testing builder pattern in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, builder

We use the builder pattern extensively in our code base, with built objects all having a `toBuilder()` method. I want to write a unit test that ensures that no fields have been forgotten in the `toBuilder()` methods, i.e., for any buildable object, I want to a test roughly like this

```
MyClass obj = getTestObjectWithRandomData();
assertEquals(obj, obj.toBuilder().build());
```

Now, I can fairly easy write a basic version of `getTestObjectWithRandomData()` that uses reflection to assign a bunch of values to the fields of any object. However, the snag is that `build()` often contains tons of validation checks that will throw exceptions if, for example, a certain integer isn't within a sane range. Writing a generalized version of `getTestObjectWithRandomData()` that conforms all those class-specific validation checks would be impossible.

So, how can I do what I want to do? I'm tempted to segregate the construction and validation code into different methods so that the test doesn't trip on the validation, but then that means that people have to remember to call `validate()` or whatever on objects after they create them. Not good.

Any other ideas?

Comment: why is it impossible to randomly assign acceptable values in the getTestWithRandomData()??

Comment: when you write code question all those if statements and throws and basically all branches and cyclomatic compexity, because you have to now go and test each of those.

Comment: In the past, I have used a static method in the class: `MyClass.createTestObject()`. It constructs a valid object without the builder, but all fields are valid. Randomness is **not** required, coverage is.

Comment: This has an unnecessary feel to me.  If you know the builder works properly once, and you've constructed it using reflection or something else that's general, why would you stop trusting it?  It seems like you're insisting on testing it for every usage because you want to see 100% code coverage.  That's a disease you should fight.

Answer (score 6):

How about using Lombok?  Would that be an option for you?  It will auto-generate the builder code and you'll never again have to worry about it.
https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder

Simply annotate your classes with `@Builder`

With Lombok

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Singular;
import java.util.Set;

@Builder
public class BuilderExample {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  @Singular private Set<String> occupations;
}
```

Vanilla Java

```
import java.util.Set;

public class BuilderExample {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Set<String> occupations;

  BuilderExample(String name, int age, Set<String> occupations) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.occupations = occupations;
  }

  public static BuilderExampleBuilder builder() {
    return new BuilderExampleBuilder();
  }

  public static class BuilderExampleBuilder {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private java.util.ArrayList<String> occupations;

    BuilderExampleBuilder() {
    }

    public BuilderExampleBuilder name(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    public BuilderExampleBuilder age(int age) {
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }

    public BuilderExampleBuilder occupation(String occupation) {
      if (this.occupations == null) {
        this.occupations = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
      }

      this.occupations.add(occupation);
      return this;
    }

    public BuilderExampleBuilder occupations(Collection<? extends String> occupations) {
      if (this.occupations == null) {
        this.occupations = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
      }

      this.occupations.addAll(occupations);
      return this;
    }

    public BuilderExampleBuilder clearOccupations() {
      if (this.occupations != null) {
        this.occupations.clear();
      }

      return this;
    }

    public BuilderExample build() {
      // complicated switch statement to produce a compact properly sized immutable set omitted.
      // go to https://projectlombok.org/features/Singular-snippet.html to see it.
      Set<String> occupations = ...;
      return new BuilderExample(name, age, occupations);
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public String toString() {
      return "BuilderExample.BuilderExampleBuilder(name = " + this.name + ", age = " + this.age + ", occupations = " + this.occupations + ")";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a good thought. I've seen that library before. My hesitation is twofold, though. One, I'm not sure my coworkers and I are ready to commit to that full-bore. Two, using Lombok means I have to give up those validation checks in the ctor. WIthout those, there's no problem.

Comment: I'm years late, but you can also override what Lombok would otherwise generate for you. I've done this on occasion to provide some of those validation checks. OTOH, the more you override lombok, the more astonishing the code becomes, so it's a mixed bag.